# How do make a profile table?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get this table on my site to have an image on the left and information about the staff member on the left. It is in a WordPress page but regardless of weather it's on the page or in a standalone HTML document it doesn't seem to render the way I want it to.

It's supposed to follow the same general idea as http://grab.by/djQk.

I attempted to copy their source but couldn't get it to render so I pulled their source from my site and started from scratch and still couldn't get it working.

http://radio.powercastmedia.net/staff/

Comment: Here is a pastebin of the code from my site: http://pastebin.com/kVGTmzUi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have implemented what you need using CSS instead of tables.

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/74Kar/)

Cheers, Sam

Answer (score 2):

If you're using tables....

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 25%;">
            <img src="blah"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Blah</td>
                    <td>Blah</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Blah</td>
                    <td>Blah</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Note: the problem with your pastebin example is that you're using `<tr>` inside a `<td>` which is incorrect - `<tr>` can only go inside a table so you need additional table tags.

It's also possible to do with a single table using `colspan` and `rowspan` on individual cells, but I'd personally prefer to do it by making the image a float left eg:

```
<div>
    <img src="blah" style="float: left;"/>
    <p>Name: John</p>
    <p>Something else</p>
</div>
```